# Problem with select Field in Formik when onChange option given

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik

I have a problem with my `<Field as="select">` in Formik. The `onChange` doesn't work well - no matter what option I choose, when I submit my form, it sends `player1` and `player2` as empty string.

E.g. output from `console.log(values)`:

```
{ id: '10', player1: '', player2: '', winner: '1', date: '2021-12-16' }
```

When I remove the `onChange` it works well, but I need onChange and selectedPlayer states, because if I pick a `player1`, I don't want him to be visible in second option and vice versa.
Why the `value` property doesn't change in my `Field` when the `selectedPlayer` is being changed? It seems like it gets the initialValue from `selectedPlayer` which is empty string.

```
import { Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {addMatchAction} from "../../ducks/matches/operations";
import {getAllPlayers} from "../../ducks/players/selectors";
import {useState} from "react";
const MatchesForm = ({ addMatchAction,error,players }, props) => {
    const handleSubmit = (values) => {

        console.log(values)
        addMatchAction(values);
    }

    const [selectedPlayer1,setSelectedPlayer1] = useState('')
    const [selectedPlayer2,setSelectedPlayer2] = useState('')
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Add match</h3>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    id: '',
                    player1: '',
                    player2: '',
                    winner: '',
                    date: ''
                }}
                onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
                enableReinitialize={true}>
                <Form>
                    <label htmlFor="id">Id: </label>
                    <Field name="id" />
                    <label htmlFor="player1">Player 1: </label>
                    <Field as="select" name="player1" onChange={(e) => setSelectedPlayer1(e.target.value)} value={selectedPlayer1}>
                        <option disabled value="">(Select a player 1)</option>
                        {players && players.map(player => {
                            if (player.id !== selectedPlayer2) {
                                return (
                                    <option value={player.id}>{player.firstName} {player.lastName}</option>
                                )
                            }
                        }) }
                    </Field>
                    <p>
                        <label htmlFor="player2">Player 2: </label>
                        <Field as="select" name="player2" onChange={(e) => setSelectedPlayer2(e.target.value)} value={selectedPlayer2}>
                        <option disabled value="">(Select a player 2)</option>
                        {players && players.map(player => {
                            if (player.id !== selectedPlayer1) {
                                return (
                                    <option value={player.id}>{player.firstName} {player.lastName}</option>
                                )
                        }
                        }) }
                        </Field>
                    </p>
                    <label htmlFor="winner">Winner: </label>
                    <Field as="select" name="winner">
                        <option disabled value="">Pick a winner</option>
                        {players && players.map(player => {
                            if (player.id === selectedPlayer1 || player.id === selectedPlayer2 ) {
                                return (
                                    <option value={player.id}>{player.firstName} {player.lastName}</option>
                                )
                            }
                        })}
                    </Field>
                    <label htmlFor="date">Date: </label>
                    <Field name="date" type="date" />
                    <button type="submit">
                        Zatwierdz
                    </button>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
            <p>{error && (<span>{error.name} {error.response.message}</span>)}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        error: state.error.error,
        players: getAllPlayers(state)
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ({
    addMatchAction
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MatchesForm);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are not understanding how Formik and this Field component work. Formik is using its own internal state to handle all Form states, so you should be using it and avoiding useState in this scenario. Here is what you can do:

- Remove onChange handler and value  as they are not allowing Formik to do its job.
- Use the function just under Formik component as it is allowed and it will allow you to access the Form state values.

Here's the code. I've also refactored the array.map functions because it is more correct to use an array filter for these scenarios (map should always return the same number of elements in the array)

```
const MatchesForm = ({ addMatchAction,error,players }, props) => {
  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
      console.log('submit', values)
      addMatchAction(values);
  }

  return (
      <div>
          <h3>Add match</h3>
          <Formik
              initialValues={{
                  id: '',
                  player1: '',
                  player2: '',
                  winner: '',
                  date: ''
              }}
              onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
              enableReinitialize={true}>
                  {props => {
                      // Try a console.log here to see props and props.values and you will see them updating on every change
                      // console.log('Values', props.values);

                      return (
                        <Form>
                        <label htmlFor="id">Id: </label>
                        <Field name="id" />
                        <label htmlFor="player1">Player 1: </label>
                        <Field as="select" name="player1">
                            <option disabled value="">(Select a player 1)</option>
                            {players && players.filter(player => player.id !== props.values.player2).map(player => (
                                <option value={player.id}>{player.firstName} {player.lastName}</option>
                            ))}
                        </Field>
                        <p>
                            <label htmlFor="player2">Player 2: </label>
                            <Field as="select" name="player2" >
                            <option disabled value="">(Select a player 2)</option>
                            {players && players.filter(player => player.id !== props.values.player1).map(player => (
                                <option value={player.id}>{player.firstName} {player.lastName}</option>
                            ))}
                            </Field>
                        </p>
                        <label htmlFor="winner">Winner: </label>
                        <Field as="select" name="winner">
                            <option disabled value="">Pick a winner</option>
                            {players && players.filter(player => player.id === props.values.player1 || player.id === props.values.player2).map(player => (
                                <option value={player.id}>{player.firstName} {player.lastName}</option>
                            ))}
                        </Field>
                        <label htmlFor="date">Date: </label>
                        <Field name="date" type="date" />
                        <button type="submit">
                            Zatwierdz
                        </button>
                    </Form>
          
                      )
                  }}
          </Formik>
          <p>{error && (<span>{error.name} {error.response.message}</span>)}</p>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you, I couldn't find anything in docs, haven't known before that it works like that!

Comment: this works but I have experienced cases where the option value doesn't update when you select another option in the options list,  any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `onChange` hander for Formik, then you're overwriting the default handler, and would need to manual `setFieldValue`

i.e.

```
onChange={(e) => {
  setSelectedPlayer1(e.target.value)
  setFieldValue('player1', e.target.value)
}}
```

What you could do as an alternative is make Formik your top-most parent component, which would allow all its children to consume its context like so:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
  const { values } = useFormikContext()
  const player1Value = values['player1']
  return <div>Player 1 is: {player1Value}</div>
}
```

This way, you don't have to do additional state management like you're doing with `useState`, it's already kept for you in Formik's context.

See here: https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext

Comment: but where should I implement setFieldValue?

Comment: @crazyfrog `setFieldValue` comes from the Formik props. Just as you have `props.values` you also have `props.setFieldValue`

Read here to get an understanding of the props object: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik